# Configuring a Tomcat subsite

Tags: java, tomcat, webserver

I have zero knowledge about Tomcat and I only need to have it working for some testing, so please forgive me if the questions is stupid.

I deployed a .war archive in Tomcat 7.0.22 (Java 1.6, MacOS Lion). The war is called "myapp.war" and so Tomcat is serving `http://localhost/myapp` (having expanded the war in /webapps/myapp). I'm fine with this.

Whenever I visit "`http://localhost/myapp`" the page won't load static files (eg: for either `/core.css` or `core.css` it looks for "`http://localhost/core.css`") while "`http://localhost/myapp/`" ( <-- note the slash!) works and serves `http://localhost/myapp/core.css`.

My web.xml:

```
<web-app>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>org.github.pistacchio.deviantchecker.core/app servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.github.pistacchio.deviantchecker.servlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>org.github.pistacchio.deviantchecker.core/app servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

How to set this up properly? Thank you

Comment: How have you declared your css in your webpage(s)?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="core.css" type="text/css" media="screen"> and <link rel="stylesheet" href="/core.css" type="text/css" media="screen"> . none works

Comment: /core.css is suppose to be the correct way. Are you doing anything special in your web.xml? If I were you, I would also attempt to deploy same app on some other container, such as Resin or Jetty ... just to be sure whether its a tomcat specific issue, or something is misconfigured in your web.xml

Answer (score 1):

If you only need it working for testing purposes the easiest solution might be to add a base html tag to the head of your webpage.

`<base href="http://localhost/myapp/" />` should do the trick.

See [this link for further explanation of the base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)